# How to pass a list of string or strings to data template in terragrunt / terraform

Tags: json, terraform, terragrunt

I encounter this problem when i am trying to pass a list of values to data template in terraform.

I tried with different methods like

`source_vpc_endpoints` as a list and taking in `["vpce-xxx", "vpce-yyy"]`,

`source_vpc_endpoints = "${jsonencode(var.source_vpc_endpoints)}"` in data.tf

and

`source_vpc_endpoints` as a string and taking in `"\"vpce-xxx\", \"vpce-yyy\""`,

`source_vpc_endpoints = var.source_vpc_endpoints"` in data.tf

terragrunt.hcl

```
  source_vpc_endpoints = "vpce-xxx,vpce-yyy"
```

Data.tf

```
data "template_file" "resource_policy" {
    template = file("resourcePolicy.json")

    vars = {
        resource = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway_rest.arn
        source_vpc_endpoints = "${jsonencode(split(",", var.source_vpc_endpoints))}"
    }
}
```

Resource policy:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "${resource}",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpce": "${source_vpc_endpoints}"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Every single one of them returns me this error:

Console:
Error: "policy" contains an invalid JSON: invalid character 'v' after object key:value pair

```
  on aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy.tf line 4, in resource "aws_api_gateway_rest_api_policy" "policy":
   4:   policy = data.template_file.resource_policy.rendered


[terragrunt] 2020/12/23 17:35:07 Hit multiple errors:
exit status 1
```

Is there a way to fix this ?

i am using terraform (0.12.29) and terragrunt (v0.23.2) aws provider ("~>v3.21.0")

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you can do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `template_file`, I think it would be easier to use [templatefile](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) where you can pass complex variables into.

```
variable "source_vpc_endpoints" {
    default = ["vpce-xxx", "vpce-yyy"]
}

locals {
    resource_policy =  templatefile("resourcePolicy.json", {
      resource             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway_rest.arn
      source_vpc_endpoints = var.source_vpc_endpoints
    })
}
```

where `resourcePolicy.json` would be:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
      "Resource": "${resource}",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "aws:SourceVpce": ${jsonencode(source_vpc_endpoints)}
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```